# How to wrap a PHP System() or set a fixed width

Tags: php

This little problem has been keeping me busy for a few days now.

I have a PHP system() command that executes a command, like this example:

```
echo '<p>';
system (escapeshellcmd("uname -a"));
echo '</p>';
```

The output is printed to the PHP page, but i would like to limit or wordwrap the width of the lines printed and prevent the command from printing the results outside the page boundary (width of 500px).

I'm bound to using the system (escapeschellcmd()); so i'm looking for a solution that incorporates this command.

I was unable to find even a hint to a solution...

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual entry for [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), you can pass a variable as the command's second argument to save the output to that variable. Like so:

```
system (escapeshellcmd("uname -a"), $string);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the resulting string at your leisure.

Update: that's not entirely correct. The second parameter is merely the return value. The command itself returns only the last line of the console output.

If you want the raw command line output (all of it), you will have to use [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of system().

Comment: The system command is also used for several shell command, like:       system (escapeshellcmd("dig $option $host"));
and the whole result (multiple lines) are returned. I'll look info passthru()/

Comment: `ob_start();
passthru ((escapeshellcmd("dig $option $host")), $result);
$content_grabbed=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<div style="max-width: 200px;">',$content_grabbed,'</div>';`  This is how far i got. This code still gives me the same output as system. The lines are printed at full length, not respecting the 200px limit.

Comment: `ob_start();
passthru ((escapeshellcmd("dig $option @$nsr $host $type")), $result);
$content_grabbed=ob_get_contents();
$content_grabbed_wrapped = wordwrap($content_grabbed, 80, "<br />\n");
ob_end_clean();
echo '<div>',$content_grabbed_wrapped,'</div>';`

This is what gave me a close enough result. Thank you for pointing out the passthru command @mkumpan

Comment: @user2396546 Don't mention it. I do wonder, though, does it print the output to stdout by default? I would have expected it to return as a variable that you would later be able to format. Also, css might help you wrap the data correctly.